# Is it possible to automatically apply Parallelize when possible

Tags: parallelization

`Parallelize` in *Mathematica* is pretty easy to use. Most of the time, applying `Parallelize` to an expression, it tries to evaluates expr using automatic parallelization. Is there an option that `Parallelize` as a default behavior in evaluation? or there is some special reason that using `Parallelize` as the default evaluation is not a good idea?

Following are some related questions for the possible reasons why `Parallelize` should not be the default evaluation method:

1. `Parallelize` does not speed up execution all the time:

[Why won't Parallelize speed up my code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/why-wont-parallelize-speed-up-my-code)

2. Only a few functions are `Parallelize`-able

[List of Parallelize[]-able functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/list-of-parallelize-able-functions)

3. And several bugs in the function

[Why is this parallel evaluation with Dispatch[] so slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25263/why-is-this-parallel-evaluation-with-dispatch-so-slow)

[Why doesn't ParallelTable work on this very simple example?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85288/why-doesnt-paralleltable-work-on-this-very-simple-example)

Comment: "or there is some special reason that using Parallelize as the default evaluation is not a good idea?" <-- Yes; 1. Sometimes it's more harmful than helpful and will slow down things 2. Some things cannot be parallelized and this cannot be easily autodetected.  Think functions with sideeffects. It's better to have manual control over this.

Comment: @Szabolcs is it a good idea to make a list of function, when an expression contains those function, then apply Parallelize automatically?

Comment: I think this is a problem that has been worked on for a long time, and no doubt still being worked on.  *Mathematica* already automatically parallelizes some computations (e.g., via MKL). If one observes processor activity, one can see it being used occasionally with `NIntegrate`, `Reduce`, etc., although that usually indicates it's time for another coffee or to answer email.  Other relevant Q&A: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35271, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84380, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3407, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39405.

Comment: @MichaelE2 so the short answer is maybe in the future version.